# how to make category screen like aliexpress?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

how to make something like this in flutter ?

[image]

I tried to make something like this in flutter.

but widget row didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can either use `Tabbar` or `NavigationRail`. With Tabbar, wrap it in a RotatedBox will put it in vertical mode.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Image you can Used **TabBar** class or **NavigationRail** or **BottomNavigationBar** Widgets

**NavigationRail** : This Widget is the left or right of an app to navigate between a small number of views, typically between three and five. [NavigationRail](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html)

**TabBar**: A widget that displays a horizontal row of tabs. [TabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) or [Working](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs)

**BottomNavigationBar**: A widget that's displayed at the bottom of an app [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)